# Unable to identify the encoding of the text C#

Tags: c#

I have a xml file which contains information about a customer like FirstName, LastName, Address etc. The text in any of the field might be bold or italics but the problem is, it is converted to code like "55349;56400;ℎ55349;56398;55349;56415;55349;56409;55349;56412;55349;" . (The file is an output from a tool which can't be edited.) 
Note - I had to remove &# from each code to make it readable.

My question is how do I know the encoding for above codes and convert the code to normal text so that it can be processed successfully.

Comment: You lost me. bold or italics? In xml? If you open the file using an editor, how do you see it?

Comment: Hi. I looks like Unicode, when you say you removed &# from the numbers. I assume it was in front of each number? Please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122641/how-can-i-decode-html-characters-in-c which explains how do decode Unicode HTML in C#.

Comment: How do you read the XML? If you use the XmlReader, XDocument, or XmlDocument it would automatically decode &#…; entities as well as handle all the other XML edge cases. Don’t parse XML by hand.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for responding! They can come bold or italics both way. Some character might be bold, some might be italic.
I tried HttpUtility.Decode and WebUtility.Decode but the data still remains same, not converted to text.

Comment: I can try using XmlReader, XDocument as you suggested. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Those would be HTML escaped characters; try putting `&#55349;&#56400;ℎ&#55349;&#56398;&#55349;&#56415;&#55349;&#56409;&#55349;&#56412;` into [this form](https://www.freeformatter.com/html-escape.html#ad-output), and note that the unescaped string is ℎ. For methods to perform the decoding in C#, see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/122641/5085211).