# How to decrypt Unicode Hex Charater "&#xa0;"

Tags: ios, xcode, encryption, unicode, utf-8

Below is my code for Decryption :

```
    NSData *decodedData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:@"someEncryptedString" 
    options:0];
    NSData *decryptedData = [self decryptData:decodedData];
    NSString *decryptedstring = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:decryptedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
   //the text is base64 encoded one more time for ePub books,so decode it after decryption
   //this is to support HTML5 reader
  
   if (forePub) {
       NSData *doubleDecodedData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:decryptedstring 
      options:NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters];
      decryptedstring = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:doubleDecodedData 
      encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
   }
```

```
- (NSData *)decryptData:(NSData *)decodedData
{

    NSString *key = @"someKey";
    NSData *keyData = [key dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    
    CCCryptorRef cryptor = NULL;
    CCCryptorStatus status = kCCSuccess;
    
    uint8_t iv[kCCBlockSizeBlowfish];
    memset((void *) iv, 0x0, (size_t) sizeof(iv));
    
    
    status = CCCryptorCreate(kCCDecrypt, kCCAlgorithmBlowfish, kCCOptionECBMode, [keyData bytes], kCCKeySizeMinBlowfish, iv, &cryptor);
    
    if (status != kCCSuccess) {
        return nil;
    }
    
    size_t bufsize = CCCryptorGetOutputLength(cryptor, (size_t)[decodedData length],
                                              true);
    
    void * buf = malloc(bufsize * sizeof(uint8_t));
    
    size_t bufused = 0;
    size_t bytesTotal = 0;
    
    status = CCCryptorUpdate(cryptor, [decodedData bytes], (size_t)[decodedData length],
                             buf, bufsize, &bufused);
    
    if (status != kCCSuccess) {
        free(buf);
        CCCryptorRelease(cryptor);
        return nil;
    }
    
    bytesTotal += bufused;
    
    status = CCCryptorFinal(cryptor, buf + bufused, bufsize - bufused, &bufused);
    
    if (status != kCCSuccess) {
        free(buf);
        CCCryptorRelease(cryptor);
        return nil;
    }
    
    bytesTotal += bufused;
    CCCryptorRelease(cryptor);
    NSData *decryptedData = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buf length:bytesTotal];
    return decryptedData;
}
```

**O/P** comes something like below:-

```
"Conditions 1&#xa0;"
```

I want these Unicode Hex Character to be converted properly.

Comment: ```&#xa0;``` is a [HTML hex entity](https://www.freeformatter.com/html-entities.html) for _Non-breaking space_, the same as ```&#160;```.

Comment: How to convert it?

Comment: Find an equivalent for dotNET's [`HttpUtility.HtmlDecode`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/122658/3439404) in your language.