# How to convert string with HTML encoding to string with corresponding symbols?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, encoding

I use external API to migrate some data to my application. All data in JSON format. And there are links to images in this data.

The problem is that some links has HTML encoding sequences instead of real symbols. E.G:

1. What i got:

   `externalApiPath/live/userfiles/Image/img_CS FSTD(H).300 AMC1 cont&#96;d_1.PNG`
2. What i want to get:

   `` externalApiPath/live/userfiles/Image/img_CS FSTD(H).300 AMC1 cont`d_1.PNG ``

And I can't get the image by placing `externalApiPath/live/userfiles/Image/img_CS FSTD(H).300 AMC1 cont&#96;d_1.PNG` link in the browser. But I can do it with `` externalApiPath/live/userfiles/Image/img_CS FSTD(H).300 AMC1 cont`d_1.PNG ``.

So they replaced `` ` `` symbol with `&#96;` code. What I need to do to covert all ISO 8859-1 codes in the whole text to the corresponding symbols.

Comment: You may be confused with ISO 8859-1 (aka Latin 1), which is an encoding. Even so it's actually rarely used, with Windows-1252 (which is much like it, but not identical) being more common.

Comment: ISO8601 is a way of formatting dates: `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss`. What you posted has nothing to do with dates.

Comment: How was this string generated? What is the *actual* JSON string? All JSON serializers will encode special characters in strings *and* decode them upon deserialization. `&` isn't such a character, so the code that generated this string has a bug. There was no reason to emit `\&` instead of `&`. All serializers will choke on this

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, sorry, i meant ISO 8859-1 encoding, not datetime format. Updated question

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, no there is no "\" in API response. I added it in StackOverflow editor because it replaced "&#96;" with "`" by default. Now everything is okay. Updated question.

Comment: In that case, it's a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122641/how-can-i-decode-html-characters-in-c). This is basic [HTML character reference](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#character-references) decoding. *(Sorry for the error in my first edit, by the way.)*

Comment: @DenisKaminsky that's not ISO 8859-1, ie plain old Latin 1 either. Which has no code or escape sequences. `&#96;` is HTML encoding

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, you are right. Using HttpUtility.HtmlDecode i solved my problem. Thanks

Comment: @DenisKaminsky why was the problem created in the first place? Why was the data HTML-encoded before serializing to JSON? No JSON serializer would do this, this was done by code *before* generating the JSON string

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, because, as i said, i use external API to migrate some data to my application. I don't even have an access to it's source code and i don't know what's going on there.